# Give anonymous users access to only one page on SharePoint Site

Tags: forms-authentication

I only want anonymous users to access one page on my entire site collection, that is the Login page.  All other pages should not be accessible.

I tried going to manage permissions for the page, and stopped inheriting.  I could not enable anonymous access.  It seems Anonymous access is only accessible in Site Permissions, which is a bummer.  I only want anonymous users to access one page, not Lists and Libraries, or Entire Website.

I am using SharePoint 2010 Enterprise Edition.  I'm using FBA for login, and I built a custom login WP to handle FBA login.

Comment: Do you have one form where users can sign in or is there one in each site collection?

Comment: One Form. The redirectURL parameter does the magic of redirecting to the site collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the page in its own library, set the anonymous access for the site to 'Lists and Libraries'. Then you need to allow anonymous access for the single library.

If you don't want to turn anonymous access on at all, then you'll have to create your login page as an application page (and this is how you should be creating a login page imho).  The best way to do that I find is to:
Make a copy SharePoint's login page and simple.master (The master page that the SharePoint login page uses) and modify/style accordingly. Then in SharePoint's Web Application settings, set the custom login page to this page that you've created.

Comment: Thanks, I did see the option of creating a layouts page that inherited from UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.  However, I chose it would be easier to just create a page and add the login WP to it.  

Thanks! You totally nailed the answer!

Comment: I talked with our SP Admin and he too recommended layouts page, so that's what I'll be doing. Except, it'll be a custom page, with custom content and webparts.